# Run QuickTime from command line to export video

Tags: video, command-line, osx-snow-leopard, conversion, quicktime

I have a bunch of avi's I am converting to m4v, and I can do this in QuickTime by opening the video and then go 'Save As', select a folder, select the type (iPhone, Movie, etc), blah blah blah. But I have around 100 videos I want to do this with. Command line options? Or batch processing options in the GUI? Enlighten me, please.

This is QuickTime X on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a GUI, I suggest checking out [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) which does have the ability to do batch processing.

Alternatively, there are (now deprecated) command line tools available in `/usr/libexec/podcastproducer` and the replacement at `/usr/bin/pcastaction`. Specifically;

```
pcastaction encode --input=INFILE --output=OUTFILE --encoder=iphone
```

You can find more by running `pcastaction help encode`

So a sample script to do this would be as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh

for FILE in /PATH/TO/FOLDER/OF/MOVIES/*; do
    /usr/bin/pcastaction encode --basedir="/PATH/TO/FOLDER/OF/MOVIES" --input="$FILE" --output="$FILE".m4v --encoder=iphone
done
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well with paths that have spaces, but good stuff.

Comment: @Daniel Huckstep: Odd, the reason I put the quotes for the input and output was to handle files with spaces (and it tested fine with files with spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You might find [qt_tools](http://omino.com/sw/qt_tools/) useful for batch conversion. I have used it under Tiger (I had to recompile it). I am not sure how it will work on Show Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done with Quartz Composer, but it's been a while since I looked at the API.